# Robert Boyle discovery of electricity

Tags: biographical-details

I was searching for all the names who discovered electricity. As I was  seeing the names, the first name came of William Gilbert and I searched how had he discovered I got to know. Then the second name came was of Otto von guericke and I searched how had he discovered and I got to know. Next name was of Robert Boyle and when I searched I couldn't find what he did in field of electricity.

So: How Robert Boyle discovered electricity after Otto von Guericke?

Comment: See Joseph Priestley, [The History and Present State of Electricity, with Original Experiments (1769)](https://books.google.it/books?id=c3QgKCXX4nIC&pg=PA5), regarding Boyle.

Comment: See also [The Philosophical Works of the HONOURABLE ROBERT BOYLE](https://books.google.it/books?id=9cIIcuheC7cC&pg=PA513&lpg=PA506), Vol.III : The Mechanical Production of Electricity.

Comment: Thank you to clear my doubt

Comment: One should also mention the [Leyden jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) of 1745 which may be the origin of the English experiments.

Comment: Electricity was known since antiquity and I doubt that you will discover any names.

Answer (score 2):

Robert Boyle does the same experiment on electricity that is taking a body and rubbing it to make it a charged body and seeing attraction of light object.He concludes that electric phenomena only shows attraction and not repulsion like the magnet which shows both attraction and repulsion